# Authenticating against a Microsoft IIS server using Java?

Tags: java, http, iis

I want to authenticate against a website using Microsoft IIS using Java to fetch data (I have permission). But I'm new at Java and I don't know how Microsoft IIS works.

I tried using `HttpURLConnection` to send a GET request to fetch the headers, and I got this:

```
Key : null ,Value : [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]
Key : WWW-Authenticate ,Value : [NTLM, Negotiate]
Key : Vary ,Value : [Accept-Encoding]
Key : Date ,Value : [Thu, 09 Jan 2014 18:46:24 GMT]
Key : Content-Length ,Value : [1293]
Key : Content-Type ,Value : [text/html]
Key : X-Powered-By ,Value : [ASP.NET, UrlRewriter.NET 2.0.0]
Key : Server ,Value : [Microsoft-IIS/7.5]
```

I'm using this to set the authentication information:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {          
        return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "pass".toCharArray());
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried following documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html

Comment: No, I have not tried it yet. How do I use NTLM with Negotiate? The documentation only has Kerberos with Negotiate.